# Cannot connect Smooch with Mailgun

Tags: mailgun, smooch

I can't connect anymore Smooch with Mailgun. I insert all the data, then the setup returns an error on Smooch.

Contacting Smooch is **impossible** for free accounts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I just had to upgrade my Mailgun account in order to receive emails. Unfortunately no one told me.

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun has removed a required feature from their free product offering.
Please refer to this doc for a list of Mailgun features required by Sunshine Conversations: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/mailgun/#what-youll-need